# Retrieve data range with two column filters

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have sheet `Transactions` with the main data, and sheet `Report` (Active) with the name of the person and into which the metrics that will be calculated from the `Transaction` main data will be fed. First step is to retrieve the data for that person (cell `B6` in the `Report`) with another condition based on a different column.

```
var report = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var trsheet = report.getSheetByName("Transactions");
var areport = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var agent = areport.getRange('B6').getValue();

var trdata = trsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var tdata = trdata.filter(function (row) {
    return row[29] == agent && row[5] == 'Closed' ;
  });
```

This produces no errors, but an empty array for `tdata`. How do I correctly add the second condition to the filter function?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add some sample values for `Report!B6`  for data to be filtered and the expected results.

Comment: Thank you Rubén! Marios below answered the question. It was an error in the column number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code looks fine. It might not work because of the two following reasons:

**1.** You might be comparing different data types. For example agent might
be a type of string in the `Transactions` sheet and integer in your
active sheet.

It would be a good idea to try to use [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) instead:

```
var report = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var trsheet = report.getSheetByName("Transactions");
var areport = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var agent = areport.getRange('B6').getDisplayValue();

var trdata = trsheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
var tdata = trdata.filter(function (row) {
    return row[29] === agent && row[5] === 'Closed' ;
  });
```

**2.** Make also sure that in the sheet **Transactions**:

- **column F** `row[5]` contains the keyword you are looking for : `'Closed'`,
- **column AD** `row[29]` contains the value of the variable you are looking for : `var agent`.

Comment: The main issue was the wrong column, how trivial. row[6] is the correct reference. I corrected it but the code still didn't produce data.  I think the new issue had something to do with the Active sheet. Var agent was not pulling any value. I closed the script editor, reloaded the sheet, re-opened the editor, and it worked. Thank you for the pointers.